# Fundamental Difference between fn() and new fn() in javascript

Tags: javascript

In what all aspects, calling a function with and without new keyword differ in javascript?
I mean what all things are differing between?

`testFn()` vs `new testFn()`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`new` creates a new (empty) object and sets `this` to it, then calls the function, which acts as the constructor for the object (by manipulating `this`.*something*). Calling the same function without the `new` keyword would let it act on whatever `this` currently means.

Comment: Is there anything more to this?

Comment: @akp no it's really that simple. Except what was not mentioned is that if the function explicitly returns a reference type, that is returned by `new` and the created object is wasted.

Comment: Using `new` will cause the new object's prototype to be set to reference that of the first function to which the new object is passed.  I don't think that behavior can be legitimately achieved via other means.

Comment: You are right, I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

These variants are syntactically different: with "new" variant supposes that the function is a constructor. The variant without "new" supposes, that it is **not** a constructor.